# Get link element when event fired on href property

Tags: javascript, html

I use a library which let me define **href** property on my links. But this lib don't allowed to define **onclick** property.

I want to execute JS function in my link. So I defined the following line (I know it's a bad practice, but I've no choice) :

```
<a href="javascript:get_element(this);return false;">Link</a>
```

With this line, the JavaScript function runs correctly. But I need to get the element that fired the link clicked and the preceding code gives me Window object. I know **href** property doesn't fire an event but I really need to get the link clicked.

With **button** tag it's very simple by using `onclick="get_element(this)"` but with **a** tag I don't know how to do that.

If you want to try examples : https://jsfiddle.net/j8o7qvz2/

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: just as a note - you shouldn't be using inline JS - much better to host in external JS file and attach an Event Handler

Comment: Yes for unobstrusive JS but I use a lib. I've no choice. I can't change it.

Comment: What's wrong with `<a onclick="get_element(this);">Link</a>`?

Comment: confused? how does the lib affect other JS? o.O

Comment: @Andy I suppose default behaviour - though you could add preventDefault (not sure if this is jQuery or vanilla JS - but either way, sure JS has an equiv)

Comment: I can't define properties to identify my links other than href. It's an PHP lib that offers many ways to produce tables.

Comment: Can you put the link in something and attach the event to that?

Comment: @jedema ah I see, PHP-generated code, so href is the only unique thing about the a tag? that sucks ... not sure how to get around that sorry (aside from changing/removing lib)  :/

Comment: Yes, it's PHP-generated. And I can't put the link in other tags. The lib juste gives me a way to define href property. I thought to do a loop in all links of table and detect data in href properties... but it's ugly and it will be very slow.

Comment: any pos way to extend the lib and add extended functionality for a tags?

Comment: Are you able to add another attribute to the `anchor` tag?

Comment: I can't put any attributs/properties other than href. And I can't extend library. It's PHPDatagrid (https://www.apphp.com/php-datagrid) and the main file of lib is more of 10k lines... with condensed code.... thanks for help :)

Comment: Are you able to add any external JS to help you out like Dave's answer, or not at all? I'm confused about the library constraints.

Comment: Yes I can't add JS files aside. But I've no ways to identify links otherwise than by read href property.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I hoped it existed a way to do that by using href property, but now, I think it's not possible. I will accept the David's solution that I will use in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this piece of Javascript code after generating all `anchor` tags. This will iterate to all anchor tags then set the `onclick` attribute based on the `href` then sets the `href` to `#`.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var link of links) {
  link.setAttribute('onclick', link.href);
  link.setAttribute('href', '#');
}
function get_element(element) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:get_element(this);">Link</a>
<br />
<button onclick="javascript:get_element(this);">BUTTON</button>
```

**EDIT:**

Since you can use external JS then maybe I'll add an answer with jQuery.

I don't know how jQuery does it may it iterates also but this is cleaner and shorter than Vanilla JS.

```js
$('a').attr('onclick', $('a').attr('href'));
$('a').attr('href', '#');

function get_element(element) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<a href="javascript:get_element(this);">Link</a>
<br />
<button onclick="javascript:get_element(this);">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Thanks you, I tought to looping over a tags but I wanted a greatest solution because the table can contains many lines. I think if it's not possible to get tag on href event, I will accept your solution as best solution.

Comment: just a note for your loop in jquery: `$('a').each(function(){console.log($(this))})` - also worth nothing, if you use jQuery - you can get rid of all inline js